# The text was not showing in the grid

Tags: css, gridview, native-base

Here is a list view with grid and detail within the grid with React Native 0.63.2 app. Within a grid, the left-most image shows up fine. However that text is not showing. Here is the code:

```
import { Container, Header, Title, Content, List, ListItem, Footer, FooterTab, Button, Left, Right, Body, Icon, Text } from 'native-base'; //ver 2.15.2
import FastImage from 'react-native-fast-image';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';  //ver 0.2.2

const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

function ListBlock ({item}) {
  return( 
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
          <Grid style={styles.grid}>
              <Col size={1} >
                  <FastImage source={{uri:item.artimages[0].path}} style={styles.itemImage}/>                        
              </Col>
              <Col size={4}>
                <Content>
                  <Text>Hello world</Text>  //<<==text does not show. No stylesheet applied.
                </Content>                  
              </Col>
          </Grid>            
      </TouchableOpacity>
  );     
}

const App = () => {
  
  var items = [{id:1, name:"1st item", description:"this is the first item", artimages:[{path:'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/boat.png'}]},
  {id:2,name:"2nd item", description: "this is second item", artimages:[{path:'https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/baboon.png'}]}];
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header />
      <Content>
        <List>
        {items.map(item => {
          return(
            <ListItem key={item.id}>
              <ListBlock  item={item} />
            </ListItem>)
          })}
        </List>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  titleText:{
      alignItems:'center',
      alignContent:'flex-start',
      textAlignVertical:'center',
      fontSize:14
  },
  grid:{
      //width:"90%",
      height:40,
      paddingTop:2,
      paddingBottom:2,
      padding:2,
  },
  imgCard:{
      alignItems:'center',
      alignContent:'center',
      
  },
  itemImage:{
      paddingLeft:20,
      width:40,
      height:40,
  },
})
    
export default App;
```

Here is how screen shot:

[image]

How to bring up the text inside a grid?

Comment: I never used `React-native-easy-grid`... But what I *deduce* from the quite tiny [documentation](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-easy-grid) is *maybe* the `size` prop expects a percentage... So I would try `<Col size={'20%'}>` and `<Col size={'80%'}>` OR with a decimal value `<Col size={0.2}>` and `<Col size={0.8}>`

Comment: The size is in <Col size={}>. Currently the image col is 1/5 of the screen width and rest is 4/5.

Comment: The ides is to use ListItem to display a list of items and grid for detail of the item. The detail of item includes image on the left and text on the right. Now the image shows but not the text on the right in grid. The problem is likely with CSS as the text must be somewhere

Comment: Try that CSS as a test `*{color: #000 !important}` for fun.

Answer (score 0):

Use `View` instead of `Content` as a wrapper for the `Text`